# Tecla Ñ no genera evento onKeyUp en teclado software de Android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, teclado

Estoy comenzando a hacer cosillas en Android y me he encontrado con una situación que no sé resolver. Agradecería cualquier ayuda o referencia a documentación donde se explique este tipo de cosas.

Quiero capturar eventos de pulsación de teclas del teclado sofware de Android.

Pra ello abro el teclado en el dispositivo con el siguiente código, lo cual me funciona sin problemas:

```
    private void abreTeclado(){
   InputMethodManager imgr = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   imgr.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
}
```

Sobreescribo el método **onKeyUp** de la Activity para testear la pulsación de letras tal y como muestro en el código en este código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//....
@Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        Log.d("test", "Pulsada letra: " + keyCode
                + " -- " + event.getUnicodeChar() );
         return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }

//...   
}
```

La pulsación de teclas de letras "normales" (a, b, ...) las captura correctamente, pero nuestra querida letra Ñ **¡¡¡no genera el evento!!!**, o dicho de otra forma, al pulsarla no llega a invocarse el onKeyUp.

Estoy usando el teclado español en una tablet Samsung, con Android versión 5.1.1.

Un saudo y gracias.
(Felicitaciones a la inciativa de un StackOverflow en epañol)

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta? Tal y como está escrito ahora, es algo interesante pero parece más una afirmación/curiosidad que una pregunta. ¿Quieres que se lea?¿Buscas una alternativa?¿qué es lo que intentas lograr?

Comment: Quiero poder capturar el evento de pulsación de la tecla ñ, para escribirla en un TextView.

Comment: Con las letras ascii normales lo hago sin problemas pero la ñ no se como capturar el evento de pulsación.

Comment: He comprobado que el método dispatchKeyEvent sí que recoge el evento de pulsación de la Ñ. Con esto y puedo continuar. Gracias. @alvaro